# HTML to EXCEL -> simple question

Tags: html, excel

O have a ,,export to excel" function, I have some tables and it works fine, but I have one single problem.

For moving to the next line I use `<br />`, but what if I want to switch to the next column? What tag can I use to switch to the next column?

Thanks

Comment: The tab key? Your question is very confusing. What application are you using to export to excel?

Comment: I'm not using any application at all, I put the html code into a file with .xls extension.... it shows ok, but I need to add informations on all the columns, not only on the first ons

Comment: You're using HTML tables? In that case, you should use the [`<table>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html), like `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Comment: I'm using multiple tables, not just one, so this is not good.

Comment: You can use multiple tables in one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple HTML tags are supported on a limited basis by Excel.  There used to be a list of supported HTML tags as well as some HTML extensions supported by Excel (from Excel 97 onwards), but I can't find it on MSDN anymore.  Here's an alternate link:

http://www.code4lifesoftware.com/articles/msexcelreadme.htm

The new XML/HTML format supported from Excel 2000 onwards is a lot more complex, and requires more work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnoffxml/html/ofxml2k.asp

Take a look at these links, hopefully you'll find the syntax you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In all Excel versions where I used this approach no other way to go to another column, but to use the table. You can mark up your html file with a table layout (although this is not recommended by W3C), and place all of the nested data table inside the main layout table. Unfortunately no other way.

P.S.: [Look at Excel html format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx): Saving and Opening HTML Files.

*The **BR** tag has a **mso-data-placement** style attribute specifying where the data is stored. The attribute can have one of the following string constants: **new-cell** means to start a new cell in the next row after the break and **same-cell** means that the break is in a cell.*

Answer (score 0):

If you use commas and make your file a .csv, that would be one way.  If you use tabs, then have it read as a tab delimited file.  Basically, you need to tell Excel what your delimiter (separator character) is, and it will handle it from there.

Comment: It's just the html code, just like you had a html file, but with extension .xls. It opens okay, but I can't switch to B1,B2,B3,B4,B5 , All my informations are stored in A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,etc etc..... Do you understand? I need to go to B1 or C1 for example and store some informations there

Comment: @FinalDestiny - Here's some information on telling Excel what delimiter (character) you use to change columns.  Does the idea of a delimiter make sense?  http://www.journalofaccountancy.com/Issues/2003/Jul/MakeExcelALittleSmarter.htm

Comment: yah, but I want to do this through html, and not in excel. When I save the excel file, it should be ready with all the needed changes.

Comment: Why not export your HTML to CSV, then?